# Need explanation on how pandas.drop is working here

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame, lets say xyz. I have written code to find out the % of null values each column possess in the dataframe. my code below:

```
round(100*(xyz.isnull().sum()/len(xyz.index)), 2)
```

let say i got following results:

```
abc               26.63
def               36.58
ghi               78.46
```

I want to drop column ghi because it has more than 70% of null values.

I achieved it using the following code:

```
xyz = xyz.drop(xyz.loc[:,round(100*(xyz.isnull().sum()/len(xyz.index)), 2)>70].columns, 1)
```

but , i did not understand how does this code works, can anyone please explain it?

Comment: ghi is a column name, 26.63 is the percentage of null values in that column

Comment: got it, follow up question is: do you want to remove the column from your dataframe? if so you can just do `xyz= xyz.drop('ghi', axis = 1)` if you want to dynamically select the columns, then look at WeNYoBen's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the code is doing the following:

```
xyz.drop( [...], 1)
```

removes the specified elements for a given axis, either by row or by column. In this particular case, `df.drop( ..., 1)` means you're dropping by axis 1, i.e, column

```
xyz.loc[:, ... ].columns
```

will return a list with the column names resulting from your slicing condition

```
round(100*(xyz.isnull().sum()/len(xyz.index)), 2)>70
```

this instruction is counting the number of nulls, adding them up and normalizing by the number of rows, effectively computing the percentage of `nan` in each column. Then, the amount is rounded to have only 2 decimal positions and finally you return True is the number of `nan` is more than 70%. Hence, you get a mapping between columns and a True/False array.

Putting everything together: you're first producing a Boolean array that marks which columns have more than 70% `nan`, then, using .`loc` you use Boolean indexing to look only at the columns you want to drop ( nan % > 70%), then using `.columns` you recover the name of such columns, which then are used by the `.drop` instruction.

Hopefully this clear things up!

Answer (score 2):

If you code is hard to understand , you can just check `dropna` with `thresh`, since `pandas` already cover this case.

```
df=df.dropna(axis=1,thresh=round(len(df)*0.3))
```